# Looking for Geocoding / Mapping advice for iPad development

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps, geocoding, openstreetmap

Some friends of mine and I are developing an app for rural service providers in our state to take their lists of customers' addresses and plot them onto a pannable map to not only display the locations, but to interact with the database information stored on our servers as well (updates from service calls, deliveries, sales, etc.).

We are new to iPad development (two of us are familiar with Android development but the potential clients are invested in iOS technology), and we have run into a geocoding quandary. It seems that our plans for geocoding would either run afoul Google's geocoding / maps APIs, or require that hefty $10,000 business license.

As a workaround, we've been thinking about hosting an Open Street Map tile server for one  village as a demonstration piece for sales purposes, and dealing with any commercial licensing if and when the product is successful.

I guess my question is out of ignorance. Does anyone have experience creating native, for-profit iOS apps that utilize Google Maps APIs (maps, directions, geolocating)? If so, is Google the best suite of tools, or would another engine be a better fit (Bing, MapQuest, Yahoo!)? Is there another better, simpler, more elegant solution to getting these locations on the map?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

I work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we maintain a geocoding (and verification) API called [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api). I figure you're running into TOS and volume limits with Google/Bing/etc APIs. LiveAddress has a much more flexible TOS.

I'm aware of several very prominent iOS developers which use LiveAddress with their apps in the app store and have found it to be very worthwhile. Keep in mind that unlike regular geocoding APIs, LiveAddress will [confirm the validity and completeness](http://smartystreets.com/what-is/cass-processing) of the address instead of approximating it, while returning only valid suggestions if needed. This will help ensure that only high-quality data goes into your database and thus, into your customers' hands.

As Jesse mentioned, iOS 6 has some spiffy new maps built-in, so you may consider looking into using those. I'm not sure what the implications are as far as availability and licensing, maybe there aren't any since it's so proprietary to just iOS devices. Let me know what you find, I'd be interested to know!

Comment: Doing research to post this question, I did come across SmartyStreets. At first we were optimistic, but because accurate geolocation is so important to the app, we ran several tests addresses through.  The first address was 3.807 miles from its correct latitude and longitude. Naturally, that worried me about the accuracy we can expect from SmartyStreets.

Comment: @J.Maxon Comparing our coordinate data against those of StrikeIron, ServiceObjects, Geocoder.us, IntelligentSearch, Cdyne, and others, you'll find that all these services essentially use the same official data -- which isn't always super-close. Results vary because of individual implementations, but in our research we found that all providers were sometimes 5 or 6 miles away. In fact, our results came closer than theirs in many cases. You can get rooftop level accuracy from some services, but not for cheap: it will cost thousands upon thousands of dollars.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yeah, I guess we're in for thousands and thousands of dollars, then. Being able to locate these customers accurately is what we're after. Shucks.

Comment: I suggest you show on your maps a radial boundary to indicate the approximation. This is common even for Google to do (when they don't have rooftop level data, which they've mainly gathered themselves through Street View and similar projects, which is one reason why it's so expensive). We'll be able to indicate the accuracy to you, from Zip5-level precision (5-digit ZIP code) to Zip9-level (about block-level). Other than structure-level data, the precise location is hit-or-miss across the board.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is SmartyStreets used mostly to verify addresses for mail delivery or do people who need structure-level accuracy use your service to first validate addresses, then feed that data into another (Google, Bing, Yahoo!) API? How do people most commonly use your service?

Comment: Good question -- it's actually both. Some apps use our service to verify an address in real-time with the user before something is mailed; others use it to ensure a *real* address before plugging it into a map API which would only approximate it otherwise. For example, [here's an address](http://goo.gl/maps/4ZXk) that looks real, but it actually lies on an intersection. You can't tell from [the geocoding results](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7580%20E%20Big%20Canyon%20Dr,%20Anaheim,%20CA&sensor=false) that it's not real except maybe for the "location_type" value.

Answer (score 1):

[MapQuest offers an iOS Maps API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api), which allows you to choose between 'regular' MapQuest tiles that are generated from licensed (commercial) data sources, or, the MapQuest-OSM tiles that are free and generated from OpenStreetMap data.  The iOS Maps API was in beta for the past few months, but the [first production version of the API was just released](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2012/07/19/ios-maps-api-1-0-1-released/).

As far as geocoding is concerned, a [MapQuest Enterprise Solutions](http://platform.mapquest.com) account manager could answer those questions and possibly quote you a price for an enterprise license if it is needed for what you would like to accomplish with your app.  Enterprise licenses provide an SLA, Technical Support, etc.  I believe the Community Edition license (free, but licensed data - not OpenStreetMap data) [allows for 5,000 geocodes per day](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview).

The [forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums) on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com) are also a good resource for finding answers to questions about the iOS Maps API, so be sure to take a look!

Hope this information is helpful!

Comment: Well, I certainly appreciate the insight into MapQuest. I think I'll have one of our developers contact them.

Do you have any affiliation with MapQuest yourself, or if not, do you have any experience using their API?

Comment: I work at MapQuest -- I just learned (today) that I should be disclosing this when I answer questions, so I apologize for any confusion.  I'm not trying to sell things, but just wanted to mention it since it's another option that could possibly work for your app.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into the new features of iOS 6 with your developer's access to Apple

Answer (score -1):

I did some research into this a few weeks back and the only pricing info I found (without contacting the relevant companies) was that Bing is 'probably' cheaper than Google Maps. But on another note Apple are working on their own maps software because they're not happy with the price tag of Google Map's - so as Jesse says, look into that.

Edit:
Google maps for business starts at $11,000 USD

Comment: That's about what we determined. It looked like Google is the best, but priciest, while Bing seems cheaper, and Yahoo seems less expensive than that. I am optimistic about the mapping features that'll be included in iOS 6.